# I keep getting an error saying I have no allocated memory for my node I am freeing? SIGABRT?

Tags: c, xcode, linked-list, queue

This is my `deQueue` method. I create a `tempNode` to point to the next node of `*head`. Then I free the `*head` and then assign the new `*head` to equal `tempNode`.

I could have sworn I had this working earlier. I thought I had fixed this error. Any advice or direction would greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
void * deQueue(struct Node **head, struct Node **tail){
    struct Node* tempNode;

    char * nodeString = &((*head)->data);//value is set to the data of the head node
    if(*head != NULL){
        tempNode = (*head)->next;
        free(*head);
        *head = tempNode;


        return nodeString;
    }
    else{
        return NULL;
    }
};
```

Comment: Checking `if(*head != NULL){` is necessary before `char * nodeString = &((*head)->data);`.

Comment: are you sure you haven't already freed the node?

Comment: I am only a couple weeks into learning the language. How do I even check if I have already freed the node? I have breakpoints in many places when I debug it. My professor told me I shouldn't have to malloc anything in the deQueue function.

Comment: As long as you follow the correct procedure you do not have to basically check if it is already released. Yes, In the `deQueue` function, `malloc` is not necessary.

Comment: So I guess I am just not understanding why i would tell me the node being freed was not allocated? Since I am deleting it in the first place?

Comment: If you try and free the same node twice you would get an error.  The `deQueue` code looks OK, but maybe the code that calls it is the problem.  Perhaps printing out the address of the node being freed would let you know if you're calling it twice.